# iconv illegal input sequence at pos... Postgres DUMP

Tags: postgresql, encoding, utf-8, iconv, pg-dump

I have a Postgres dump from a database that is in SQL_ASCII.

I've created it using `pg_dump` with `-E UTF-8` modifier.

But I can't restore it in a newly created database with encoding UTF-8 without errors (See: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4777/how-to-solve-utf8-invalid-byte-sequence-copy-errors-on-a-restore-when-the-sourc).

The schema is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BysjmDTkzZpLRlp4QjBwTGdnaTA/view?usp=sharing

Since I have problems when importing it, I am trying a solution given in DBA before, converting it to UTF-32

`iconv -f UTF-8 -t UTF-32 -o schema_32.sql schema.sql`

But then I have this error: `iconv: illegal input sequence at position 703914`

Comment: For *only a few* errors: move the offending line(s) to a new text file, and edit that file manually.

Comment: Why on earth would UTF-32 help?

Comment: PostgreSQL 8.2 didn't validate UTF-8 as well as more recent versions do. Most likely you've got bad utf-8 that 8.2 accepted, but newer versions won't. I'd use a text editor to fix the dump file's bad utf-8 data.